# gradle build error Plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found

Tags: java, android, gradle

I've been trying to build my android app with gradle build, and to get it download required dependencies and jar files automatically, I added in my settings.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
```

And my build.gradle looks like this

```
plugins {
    // Apply the application plugin to add support for building a CLI application in Java
}
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.8.1'
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:30.1.1-jre'
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1'
}
application {
    mainClass = 'MyProject.App'
}
tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

When I try running gradle build, I get an error:

```
A problem occurred while evaluating settings 'MyProject'.
> Plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found.
```

I did some research, and every answer on the Internets says it's probably due to the plugin version, so I tried solving the problem by using versions 4.1, 4.2, 7.1, and 7.0 for of 'com.android.tools.build:gradle', with no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding plugins in wrong place.

Plugins are added inside `build.gradle` (app) and classpaths are added inside `build.gradle` (project).

For example, inside `build.gradle` (app)

```java
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
buildscript {
    repositories { 
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies { }
}
    
inside build.gradle(Project)
    
dependencies{
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1'
}
```

Comment: But moving the "apply plugin" lines to build.gradle resulted in another error: `Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.library'. Cannot add a configuration with name 'lintClassPath' as a configuration with that name already exists

Comment: Putting "id 'com.android.application' version '7.0' apply false" in the plugins block (as mentioned in https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin) did not work either...

Answer (score 0):

*Updated April 2, 2022*

You need to update to the latest gradle version to solve this issue.

Please make sure you are on the latest Android Studio, and then update your project level `build.gradle` by updating this dependency:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter() 
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1'
    }
}
```

It might show a popup asking your permission to update gradle, please update and it will download the latest distribution automatically and the issue will be resolved.

Or else you can download gradle manually:

Open `YourProject > gradle > wrapper > gradle-wrapper.properties` and replace

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-version-number-all.zip
```

With

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.1.1-all.zip
```

Rebuild the project or just run gradle sync again, and it should work.